# Как скопировать значение массива в строку

Tags: c#

Скажите, пожалуйста, у меня я получилось скопировать елемент массива в массив, но как скопировать в строку что-бы отредактировать текст.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string [] items = {"one","two","three","one","two","one"};
        string [] a = {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"};
                
        items[3] = a[3];
        
        Console.Write(items[3]);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если хотите отредактировать `items[3]`, то для этого можете просто написать `items[3] = "ваше_новое_значение"`. Не обязательно копировать значение в отдельную переменную... тем более, в C# строковый тип данных является неизменияемым типом данных, поэтому нет никакого смысла в создании отдельной переменной для редактирования строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (items[index] == "one") {
  string s = items[index];
  s = s + " Mississippi"; 
  items[index] = s;
}
```

---

*"Чтобы" пишется вместе.*